# How to add ConfigServer Firewall to Monit?

Tags: centos7, monit, csf

Does anybody know how to monitor CSF with Monit? I can't find any examples nor csf.pid file on CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Although a pidfile Is prefered, Monit is capable of monitoring processes that do not produce a pid file. It looks like CSF's running daemon is called "lfd"? Here is an example.

> CHECK PROCESS ConfigServerFirewall MATCHING lfd